# GCM not giving Token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Can you help me out here? My code was working like 3 days before. Now when I run, i cant get GCM token generated for my device. Here is my code:

```
 private void registerGCM() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String token = null;

    try {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);


        Log.e(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        // sending the registration id to our server
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);

        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", token);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
```

Comment: Check your `gefaultSenderId` and make sure you haven't disable `GCM API.`

Comment: check your .json file in app folder

Comment: ok i checked, my API_KEY is the same  in Android API key in Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a registration token, Google provides the [`Instance ID API`](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) to handle the creation and updating of registration tokens.

You must include the `InstanceIDListenerService` in your manifest file to use this.

```
<service android:name="[.MyInstanceIDService]" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then to obtain a token, call [`instanceID.getToken`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID), providing the app server's sender ID and setting the scope to `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE`.

> NOTE: Do not call this method in the main thread; instead, use a
>   service that extends
>   [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Here is the sample code for this.

```
Public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // ...
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);


        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

For more information, just check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) and this complete [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java#L52-L54).